# Linux Centos 7, how to install the siunix LaTeX package?

Tags: linux, latex, centos7

I'm using Kile on a Linux CentOS 7 system. I need to install the `siunix` package for LaTeX but I do not know how to do it.

I tried to clone the git repository as explained [here](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx) but it did not work. I did not find any other instruction for Centos 7.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is not just a typo? The package is called `siunitx`, not `siunix`.

Maybe have a lok at your package-manager yum, for me (in Arch) there is texlive-siunitx package.

Alternatively copy / unzip the files from github and then run the install.sh script, it should install everything you need.

I cannot test it myself as I don't run centOS, Sorry :)

Comment: Thanks! `sudo yum install -y texlive-siunit` was the right command